# Problem in synchronize bookmark to SourceForge server

Tags: mercurial

I add a bookmark to my local repository through

TortoiseHg -> Repository Explorer -> Tag -> Add/Move/Remove Bookmark

Later, I perform push to [ssh://yccheok@jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/jstock/jstock](http://ssh://yccheok@jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/jstock/jstock)

I realize 0 changset is being pushed, and bookmark is not shown in

http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/graph (Use getWeekOfWeekyear instead of getWeekyear.)

Later, I clone the repository to another machine, I realize there are no bookmark information being clone from sourceforge server.

I was wondering why this happen? Is it because SourceForge is using a version of mercurial server which doesn't support bookmarking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks aren't normally pushed and pulled, you have to specifically ask them to be.

If you want persistent, global (between all clones), "bookmarks", use tags instead. Bookmarks are intended as lightweight transient tags, ie. "this is where I'm currently working".

Comment: tag is not suitable as there will be further committed activities on that branch. can you be more specific on how to ask them to push and pull automatically?

Comment: You can specify the bookmark name to the push and pull commands (command line) through the use of the -B or --bookmark options, but I don't know if you can do it using the TortoiseHg GUI client. Also, I have no idea if this requires support in the target repository server or not. It might, in which case it depends on the version SourceForge is running whether this will actually work or not. You should experiment with a couple of dummy repositories locally first to get the syntax right.

Comment: Also, since you say "further committed activities", are you sure you don't want to name the branch instead?